# App crashes when remove a section in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to delete a cell and remove a section from a UITableView with the following code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[arraymasterFeedFullDetails removeObjectAtIndex:cellSelectedIndexPath.section];
[self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:cellSelectedIndexPath.section]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Here,cellSelectedIndexPath is NSIndexPath variable which is pointing to the section is currently selected. arraymasterFeedFullDetails is my datasource and only one row per each section.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return [arraymasterFeedFullDetails count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Give details of the crash message and stack trace

Comment: here in the numberOfSectionsInTableView you have to remove one object from arraymasterFeedFullDetails every time when you delete a section..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243834/crash-when-deleting-row-inconsistency-in-section-not-being-updated?rq=1

Comment: I got this crash message:                                                              Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (6) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

Comment: So the message says that you started with 5 sections, deleted one but at the end of all that `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returned 6 - one *more* than you started with. Have you set a breakpoint and examined your array?

Comment: You must update the datasource as well when you perform this deletion.

Comment: reason of crashing? any exception, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a data source(`arraymasterFeedFullDetails` in your case), the thing you need to do to delete an item, is to remove object from data source and then reload the table.

You can reload the table using `[self.tableView reloadData];`

So your code would be like this:

```
[arraymasterFeedFullDetails removeObjectAtIndex:cellSelectedIndexPath.section];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: this way, it would reload whole tableview instead of removing only desired cell by animating out.  Instead you could follow the OPs approach and update the datasource, and that solves the problem.

Comment: No, there is no reason to call 'reloadData`. Just remove the one section.

Comment: [tableView reloadData]  loads full tableview, I wants to  to know how to load only one section.  As i have large number of sections in a table.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a data source(arraymasterFeedFullDetails in your case), the thing you need to do to delete an item, is to remove object from data source and then either reload the whole table, or, remove the cells from the datasource with animation. 
This in general will produce a visually better result.

The reloadData method will reload the whole table, without animation.
Currently shown cells will be simply redrawn. E.g.:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

You won't need to update the tableview itself, as this will be simply redrawn.

In order to remove just "edited away cells", with an animation effect, you can use the method **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:  withRowAnimation:**

E.g.:

```
    // Overridden to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            [_list2 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // remove row from array
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; // remove cell from UITableView
        } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
```

You could also remove rows from your **mutable** array, then call 
**deleteSections:withRowAnimation:**
between **beginUpdates** and **endUpdates** in order to delete a whole section from your tableview;

In both animated deletion approaches, you will need to **make sure that the data source has the same count of the tableview cells (after the deletions)** before doing any animation which will update the tableview.

Comment: This isn't valid either. The OP wants to remove an entire section, not one row. Use the `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`.